# Dynamic arrays in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am trying to dynamically create an array of rectangles with random values. However when trying to access the space I `malloc` I get a seg fault.

My Code:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
} PointT;

typedef struct Rect
{
    PointT location;
    char color;
    double w; //width
    double h; //height
} RectT;
main()
{
    RectT *recs;
    randRect(&recs);
}
void randRect(RectT **rects)
{
    int i;
    rects =malloc(numRec*sizeof(RectT*));
    for(i = 0; i < numRec-1; i++)
    {
          rects[i]->w=rand()%20;
          rects[i]->h=rand()%20;
          rects[i]->location.x=rand()%20;
          rects[i]->location.y=rand()%20;
    }
}
```

`numRec` is defined as `50`

Comment: Change `rects =malloc(numRec*sizeof(RectT*));` to `*rects =malloc(numRec*sizeof(RectT));`.

Comment: It seems you need to decide if you want an array of pointers to `RectT` or `RectT` as `sizeof(RectT*)` is not the same as `sizeof(RectT)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rects in a function is a pointer to a pointer. So you need to allocate array of RectT items before using it. It should be like this:

```
void randRect(RectT **rects)
{
    int i;
    *rects =malloc(numRec*sizeof(RectT));
    for(i = 0; i < numRec; i++)
    {
      (*rects)[i].w=rand()%20;
      (*rects)[i].h=rand()%20;
      (*rects)[i].location.x=rand()%20;
      (*rects)[i].location.y=rand()%20;
    }
}
```

Or even better way:

```
Rect* randRect()
{
    int i;
    Rect* rects =malloc(numRec*sizeof(RectT));
    for(i = 0; i < numRec; i++)
    {
      rects[i].w=rand()%20;
      rects[i].h=rand()%20;
      rects[i].location.x=rand()%20;
      rects[i].location.y=rand()%20;
    }
    return rects;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a "pointer to a pointer". But in C syntax of accessing items of rect[] and rect* is invariant. Which is actually used in this sample. That's why I wrote "pointer to an array".

Answer (score 2):

You allocate space for an array of `RectT` *pointers*, but you never allocate space for the `RectT`s that they point *to*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate space for rectangles, not for pointers to rectangles:

```
void randRect(RectT **rects) }
  *rects = malloc(numRec * sizeof(RectT));

  for (size_t i = 0; i != numRec; ++i) {
    (*rects)[i]->w = 0; // etc
  }
}
```